# Many dex files on one machine

Tags: android, gradle, dex, android-min-sdk

I have three machines that I used to build my android project. On all machines, I have the same code, same grade, and same gradle.properties. On all machines is windows.

I have min SDK 23.

On one machine, my APK has 48MB and contains 473 dex files.
On other machines, my APK has 40MB and contains 11 dex files.

Any advice why my APK is bigger on one machine? And why I have too many dex files on one machine?